# Power Point Presenstion with transitions Swift

Tags: ios, swift, powerpoint, quicklook

I am working on an project where i need to show the ppt with all transition which were defined in PowerPoint editor, During R&D i come across [QUICK LOOK](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook) which just displays the ppt but could not show the transitions, is there any other way to show the transitions.

Comment: Too broad but my guess is you should research using a PowerPoint online viewer together with WebKit

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Look** is exactly what it describes: a quick look at a file, without the animations and transitions that may be added. To view the file with transitions, open it in PowerPoint or [PowerPoint Online](https://www.office.com/launch/powerpoint).